# Jenkins pipeline stage with variable in string parameter

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline

I need to pass a variable into a string parameter from another job . I have the parameterised string variable as `entaClient`. See `taskFilterName` & `tasksGroup`

How do I get this to work?

```
stage('Restart the Enta API') {
    steps {
        script {
            if (params.hotReload.contains('Hot Reload')) {
                build(job: 'Hot Reload (utility)',
                    parameters: [
                        string(name: 'region', value: params.region),
                        string(name: 'cluster', value: params.cluster),
                        string(name: 'taskFilterName', value: enta-${entaClient}-dev-api-),
                        string(name: 'tasksGroup', value: enta-${entaClient}-dev-api-a,enta-${entaClient}-dev-api-b,
                        string(name: 'containerInstanceIdsToStartOn', value: params.containerInstanceIdsToStartOn)
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation)

```
string(name: 'taskFilterName', value: "enta-${entaClient}-dev-api-")
```